# Vampire protects last remaining humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story in a vampire anthology? The vampire protects the last remaining humans from being killed and drained by other vampires. he knows that letting the other vampires kill the humans would doom the rest of the vampires to unending hunger.

Comment: Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details? Thanks.

Comment: Ok it was probably the 80s when i read this. I remember the hero vampire would eat drain rats of their blood. The humans didnt know he was protecting them from the starving vampires. the band of humans just wandered looking for a place to stay in safety. I always thought it wouldve made a terrific movie or tv show.

Comment: Im pretty sure there was a little girl that thought she saw the hero vampire. He would kill and drain rats to stave of the incredible hunger he felt. The humans didnt know he was protecting them from other vampires that were insane with hunger

Comment: i was reading and collecting quite a few Azimov anthologies back then too. there seemed to be an anthology for every genre with azimovs name on them.

Comment: Perhaps in one of [these anthologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Isaac_Asimov_anthologies)?